# external drive for ios products

Tags: ios, external-disk

I just purchased a `cloud ftp` usb adapter for my ipad so i can access my data.
What these companies dont tell you is that the ipad must sync or download the files **from** hdd **to** ipad to access the data, which makes it ridiculous if your trying to watch video or listen to music.
**My question is:** Does anyone know how to stream the data from an external storage device so that accessing feel natural like a laptop?

**edit**: `Air Video` with a mac mini server pretty much did what i was looking for. 
Hopefully a HDD that offers something similar will be available soon.

Comment: and you have joined the adapter's network and visited its hosted web-app?  it should work as expected.  http://www.hypershop.com/v/vspfiles/downloads/CloudFTP-quick-start-guide.PDF

Comment: It opens files in safari, was hoping I can choose other apps

Comment: it looks like that's their only supported solution for CloudFTP... you could always use File Sharing on a Mac and use the app [FileBrowser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/filebrowser-access-files-on/id364738545?mt=8) for the iPhone. specifically, what apps are you trying to use your external storage data with?

Comment: i wanted to watch video and listen to music

Comment: I believe vlc can stream from ip but it didn't work w/ cloudftp

Comment: VLC is not offered on the App Store any more, if I'm not mistaken...(unless you got it before it was pulled) Why do you need to use anything other than Safari to watch the videos and listen to music from the web app? further, why don't you just sync them via iTunes? a usb key plugged into a cloud ftp adapter to stream is not as efficient as just having it on the iPad itself.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but i dont like the constant writing to disk

Comment: I'm very interested in an answer, since I basically have zero space on my ipad, certainly not enough to sync a movie or multiple songs now.

Answer (score 2):

Apple TV does most of this especially if u pay $25 a year for iTunes Match. Anything downloaded is available on all devices including the Apple TV...

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use Dropbox for this? You can copy your audio and video to your Dropbox folder, install the Dropbox client on your computers and mobile devices, and let it keep your files in sync across all of your machines.